# iOS - Trying to setup Autolayout on subviews in layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

I have a class which is initialized at first with no frame set - ClassA below.  The instance of ClassA is NOT setup with autolayout.  It's frame is set manually later.  However, I want ClassA's subview to be auto laid out.  Problem is I can't find the right way to do this.  If I try to setup the constraints before layoutSubview is called (before frame is set), the constraints won't validate.  If I try to set them up after calling Super in layoutSubviews, I get this

Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. GHTExerciseSetView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.

If I try to setup the constraints after the call the Super (which doesn't seem right anyway), it seems to work at first but when I start adding more instances of ClassA and redrawing, I get more problems with the constraints not validating.  The main question, it what is the proper way to layout views this way.  Thanks.

```
@interface ClassA ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) SubView1 *sub1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SubView2   *sub2;


@end

@implementation ClassA

//this is called initially with no frame
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
      sub1 = [[SubView1 alloc] init];
      sub1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
      [self addSubView:sub1];

      //Same for sub2

}
 return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubViews {
     [super layoutSubViews];
}

- (void)updateConstraints {   
    [super updateConstraints];

    //sub1 and sub2 constraints
}
```

Comment: Can you show what the view should look like with the constrained sub views. i.e. how should the subviews be laid out etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your constraints are being configured correctly.

After you create the view hierarchy in `initWithFrame:`, try sending `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` to `self`. Doing this in my own app seemed to resolve some issues.

Also, `updateConstraints` may get called multiple times, so make sure you're not installing the same constraints over and over again.